# forward declaration not working , does not have a type error

Tags: forward-declaration, circular-dependency

I use forward declaration but still get ERROR: 'link' does not name a type. Why?

```
struct link;

struct node
{
    link *head_link;            <------- this is the error location
    node *next_node;
};

struct link
{
    link *next_link;
    node *connect_node;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare a type called struct link, it's not just link, so write:

```
struct node
{
    struct link *head_link;
    struct node *next_node;
};
```

Alternatively, declare a type called link with a `typedef`.

Comment: So I change the forward declaration to 
struct node; and have the real struct link declaration come before the real struct node declaration, it still give me the same error: 'link' does not name a type. Wouldn't it give me error for the 'node'?  On the other hand, how I can typedef forward declaration so that the name link and node are preserved?

Comment: I replaced all the word 'link' with 'edge' and it complied without issue. I guess link is a keyword that I didn't know about.